# Associating a File extension with a pure E4Editor

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

how can I associate a pure E4Editor with a file ending?
I created a feature containing some plugins, in which the editor is implemented. I'am contributing my feature into an legacy E4 application via installation of my feature via p2 updatesite.
Where can I define the file association for my editor. Can I define this in my fragment.xmi or programmatically?

Thanks in advance,
Sebastian.

Comment: What do you mean by a 'pure e4 editor'? e4 only has parts not editors and views.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I meant an e4 part.

Comment: This 'legacy e4 application' - e4 does not have anything for file associations - do you mean an Eclipse 4 application using the 3.x compatibility code? If you do you will have to write a traditional editor part.

Comment: And what would be the correct way, when developing a pure e4 application? Is there really no way to associate a part with a file extension, e.g. a double-click on artifact in project explorer opens the part?

Comment: A pure e4 application does not have any inbuilt file system (other than the Java APIs), no editors, no file associations. If you want these in e4 you do them yourself (which I did for one of my e4 apps) or you revert to the traditional 3.x style.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments a pure e4 application does not include any of the editor features as provided by Eclipse RCP 3. So if you would want to associate a file extensions with an editor, you'd first have to bring in the concept of filetypes and editors!

Though it's not really hard to implement these features in E4 yourself. And Tom Schindl has done just that in a demo he calls [The Simple e4 IDE](http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2010/05/31/the-simple-e4-ide/). You can find the source code [right here](https://eclipse.googlesource.com/e4/org.eclipse.e4.ui/+/master/examples).

Basically, assuming you have already implemented a navigator (also in Tom's Demo!), you would start by bringing in the concept of editors. In e4 an editor would just be standard e4 part that one can save. You might be able to use the `@Persist` annotation provided by e4 for that!

And now to associate your editors with a certain filetype you'd have to provide an extension mechanism. Tom has created a new `EditPartDescriptor` that allows you register an editor with a certain fileextensions directly in the Application Model. You may also use a simple Eclipse extension point, like I have done before, if you are more familiar with that.

Now that you have found a way to connect an editor with one or more fileextensions you only need a way to open up these editors preferably with an e4 `Command` and an associated `Handler`.

Tom has simple put this logic in the `simpleide/navigator/internal/ResourceNavigator.java`, the relevant code are lines 180 to 200. Here he simply loops through all the registered `EditorPartDescriptors` checks for the filename and fires of a `ParameterizedCommand`. Though I would recommended using the `ISelectionService` to select a file and than determine and open the correct editor in a `Handler` or perhaps a even a separate service.

---

Hopefully I've provided enough information to get you started on implementing your required functionality. Looking at The Simple e4 IDE demo I've managed to implement similar functionality into my own application. And it's a great way to learn about e4 in general too!

I am happy to provide examples of my own implementation or point you in the right direction in Tom's code since I've become quite familiar with it due to my own ventures. But since there is a little confusion whether we are talking about e4 or 3.x compatibility code I'll put that off for now.

*P.S. I will also add more links to the relevant documentation once I have enough reputation.*